# Returning long-running api response as a "download"

Tags: 9

I'm working on a REST api endpoint which takes in an array of IDs, loads all of the entities associated with those IDs, does some processing on them, then returns them in a chosen format (csv, xls etc.).

This processing could take a long time with a large number of IDs, so I want to start returning data to the user immediately as if they are downloading a file (which they sort of are) and finish the download when the last entity is processed.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: This sounds like streaming the file: https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-uploads/file-streaming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excellent [comment by @Kevin](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/316079/returning-long-running-api-response-as-a-download#comment404928_316079). Drupal core doesn't use StreamedResponse, but as always the Webform module is a good resource for examples, which also shows the difference between viewing and downloading the streamed result:

*/modules/contrib/webform/modules/webform_submission_export_import/src/Controller/WebformSubmissionExportImportController.php*

```
  /**
   * Returns the Webform submission export example CSV view.
   */
  public function view() {
    return $this->createResponse(FALSE);
  }

  /**
   * Returns the Webform submission export example CSV download.
   */
  public function download() {
    return $this->createResponse(TRUE);
  }

  /**
   * Create a response containing submission CSV example.
   *
   * @param bool $download
   *   TRUE is response should be downloaded.
   *
   * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
   *   A response containing submission CSV example.
   */
  protected function createResponse($download = FALSE) {
    $webform = $this->importer->getWebform();

    // From: http://obtao.com/blog/2013/12/export-data-to-a-csv-file-with-symfony/
    $response = new StreamedResponse(function () {
      $handle = fopen('php://output', 'r+');

      $header = $this->importer->exportHeader();
      fputcsv($handle, $header);

      for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
        $webform_submission = $this->generateSubmission($i);
        $record = $this->importer->exportSubmission($webform_submission);
        fputcsv($handle, $record);
      }

      fclose($handle);
    });

    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', $download ? 'text/csv' : 'text/plain');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', ($download ? 'attachment' : 'inline') . '; filename=' . $webform->id() . '.csv');
    return $response;
  }
```

When testing this module you won't see much of a streaming effect when viewing the result in the browser because of the buffering enabled in most web servers. You need much higher numbers of items, like `$i <= 3000`, to fill up the buffers and get a streaming effect for a few seconds.

Comment: Recently added StreamedResponse to the OpenAI module. Very cool in action.